# Parentheses and if statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working through some old code and I ran into something that I think is strange in Ruby, I'm trying to wrap my head around it but I can't find anything similar to it in any documentation.

```
someMethod()
(
    someOtherStuff()
) if value > 0
```

The ruby syntax I've always seen for if statements follows a more traditional if statement, the conditional code under it, and an end tag after the conditional block.  Is this just some other way of writing that, with the call to someOtherStuff() executed conditionally on the result of value > 0?  Or is this doing something else?

Comment: It seems `someMethod()` isn't directly related to `someOtherStuff()`. You could just omit the parenthesis around `someOtherStuff()` giving you a one line statement. `someMethod;
someOtherStuff if value > 0`.

Comment: You've used [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) to name your two methods.  By convention, Ruby uses [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for that (e.g., `some_method`), and for naming variables as well. You don't have to follow that convention but 99%+ of Rubiests do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This isn't OPs code, it's been inherited by the sound of it.

Comment: @Stuart, no harm, no foul.

Comment: @CarySwoveland (thumbsup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
# Original snippet

someMethod()
(
    someOtherStuff()
) if value > 0
```

is a longer way to write

```rb
# Snippet 1

someMethod # Note that `someMethod` will always be executed
someOtherStuff if value > 0
```

If you want to use the traditional format of if statements, you could write it like this:

```rb
# Snippet 2

someMethod # Same here, it will always be executed
if value > 0
  someOtherStuff
end
```

Snippet 1 is useful for writing [guard clauses](https://www.thechrisoshow.com/2009/02/16/using-guard-clauses-in-your-ruby-code/).

Comment: Perhaps include the extra step: "...is a longer way to write `someMethod(); (someOtherStuff()) if value > 0`, which is the same as `someMethod(); someOtherStuff() if value > 0`, which is the same as `someMethod; someOtherStuff if value > 0`.